# How to change default lock screen and logon image in Windows 11 Pro via Group policy?

Tags: windows-11, group-policy

I'm trying to change the "default lock screen and logon image".

I've tried the "Force a specific default lock screen and logon image" Group Policy setting under "Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Personalization", but then I noticed that the setting only applies to Enterprise, Education and Server SKU's.

Surely there's a way of changing the default lock screen and logon image in Windows 11 Pro?